# Replace a substring with delayed expended variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to count a number of variables by comparing original string with a replacement string, from which a substring is deducted. It does work in cases with regular variables %var% and where use of delayed expansion is not required, but is there a way to make it work with delayed expansion variable !var! instead of using a 2nd FOR loop? The below code can't count pat# variables. I do realize, they can be counted using a different method, but this is just an example to illustrate my question about replacing substrings.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "pat1=A" & set "pat2=B" & set "pat3=C" & set "pat4=D" & set "pat5=E"
set "pat6=F" & set "pat7=G" & set "pat8=H" & set "pat9=I" & set "pat10=J"
set "patn=;0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;"

if not defined patc (
    for /f %%l in ('set pat') do (
        set "patl=%%l" & set "patl=!patl:~3,1!"
        if not "!patn:;!patl!;=!"=="%patn%" (set /a "patc+=1" & echo !patc!)))
exit /b
```

Comment: You cannot use delayed expansion for search (and replace) strings in a delayed expanded variable; you could use the following work-around: `for /F "delims=" %%S in ("!search_string!") do echo !variable:%%S=!`

Comment: Can delayed expended substrings be used in a regular variable? 
Like:  

`if not "%patn:;!patl!;=%"=="%patn%"` It doesn't work for me either.

Comment: No! You need to make sure that the substrings are expanded *before* the variable; so the substrings can be immediately expanded (`%`) and the variable delayed (`!`), but *not* vice versa...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use some sort of double expansion.
There are `CALL` or `FOR-parameter` possible

```
....
set "patl=%%l" & set "patl=!patl:~3,1!" & echo ;!patl!;
call echo %%patn:;!patl!;=%%

or

FOR /F "delims=" %%S in ("!patn!") do (
    echo !patn:;%%S;=!
)
```

Comment: Thanks_ jeb_ and _aschipfl_! For future readers, here's working code that allows to avoid extra FOR interations: 
Of course, in the below code IF NOT can start from a new line, but it doesn't seem to work in comments code formatting: 

`for /f %%l in ('set pat') do (
 set "patl=%%l" & set "patl=!patl:~3,1!" & call set "patm=%%patn:;!patl!;=%%" & if not "!patm!"=="%patn%" (set /a "patc+=1" & echo !patc!))`

Comment: In addition, known alternative approach is:
`for /f "delims=0123456789" %%m in ("!patl!") do (set "var=%%m") & if not defined var (set /a "patc+=1")`