# Rename Files using wildcard paths

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

Recently I started working and my first task is to write a batch file that automatically changes filenames to filename_date with the original file-ending.
For that you should be able to write paths into a textfile (e.g. paths.txt) and when you start the program, it should take any line (=path->file) from there and rename it.
I got it to work on my PC quiet well but as I gave it to testing they asked to make the use of wildcards `Z:\Path\*.*` possible.
My current code looks as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd %~dp0    

For /F "tokens=*" %%m in (paths.txt) do (

set path=%%~dpm
set name=%%~nxm

pushd "!path!"
dir

For /r !path! %%f in (!name!) do (

set path=%%~dpf
set name=%%~nf
set ending=%%~xf
set datsave=%%~nxf

set "name=!name!_"
set "name=!name!!date:~6,4!"
set "name=!name!!date:~3,2!"
set "name=!name!!date:~0,2!"

set "name=!name!!ending!"

copy "!datsave!" "!name!"

del "!datsave!"
cls
popd
)

)
```

I know that a lot of it is probably easier and more efficient to do, but this is my first batch project and I am quiet happy except for the wildcard problem. 
So an example would be:
`C:\Some\Path\*.*`

This line would be in paths.txt.
With the splitting

```
set path=%%~dpf
set name=%%~nf
set ending=%%~xf
set datsave=%%~nxf
```

I get the following:

```
path: C:\Some\Path
name: C:\Some\Path
ending: -empty-
datsave: C:\Some\Path
```

because name is set to the Path at the start of the first FOR-Loop. But that seems to be working if I do not use wildcards.

Now the question: Why does this happen and how do I get rid of it? Or do I just use the wrong type of wildcards?

Again: This is my first time I work with batch, so it might be something simple ;)

Comment: Nice try already! do you HAVE to do this using batch?

Comment: Thanks :) Unfortunately yes. I do not know the reasons, but when my boss says go for batch I have to ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weeeeell First of all thanks again to @Jean-François Fabre and @aschipfl for their patience with me :)
After the hint with the second batch file I had to test a few things as not everything worked as fine, but now everything works great!

Code of the Main file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd %~dp0
set DEPTH=20

For /F %%m in (paths.txt) do (
pause
set pth=%%~dpm

  REM pushd !pth!
  REM set origpth=!cd!
  REM popd

set z=%%m
set name=!z!

For /L %%i in (1,1,%DEPTH%) do set 
name=!name:*\=!
set chkname=!name:*\=!
if not !chkname!==!name! ( echo depth to small
pause
exit /B)

rem set name=%%~nxm
pushd "!pth!"

For /r . %%f in (!name!) do (

pushd %~dp0
call renamefiles.bat %%f REM "!origpth!"
popd
)

)
```

And the code of the sub-file:

```
@echo off   

  REM set pth=%~dp1
  REM set origpth=%2
  REM set origpth=%origpath:"=%\

  REM If !pth!==%origpth% (

set path=%~dp1
set name=%~n1
set ending=%~x1
set datsave=%~nx1

pushd !path!

set "name=!name!_!date:~6,4!!date:~3,2!!date:~0,2!!ending!"

pause

echo renaming "!datsave!" to "!name!"
rem "!datsave!" "!name!"

cls
popd

  REM )
```

EDIT: After testing around a bit I figured, that subfolders are included as well! I put extra code to both codes marked with REM and two extra spaces. Take out those REM's and the programm will not longer include subfolders when renaming :)

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I figured out 2 problems and now it works

`set name=%%~nxm` evaluates the wildcard. Even if name is `*.txt` it will return `bar.txt`.
I replaced that by a basename computation instead: `set name=!name:*\=!` done enough times (not very subtle but hey batch files forces us to do such things) which preserves the wildcard

The other problem is the `for /R loop`: after `pushd`, the argument needs to be `.` or it won't be scanned.

Last minor one: use `rename` instead of `copy` plus `delete`. It preserves file time and is very fast. Copying then deleting a large file can take a long time.

```
@echo off

set DEPTH=20
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd %~dp0    

For /F %%m in (paths.txt) do (

set pth=%%~dpm
set z=%%m
set name=!z!

rem brutal basename. We cannot break the inner loop or
rem it would break the upper loop too
for /L %%I in (1,1,%DEPTH%) do set name=!name:*\=!
rem but we can check if it is really a basename
set chkname=!name:*\=!
if not !chkname!==!name! ( echo please increase DEPTH value
pause
exit /B)

rem set name=%%~nxm
pushd "!pth!"
For /r . %%f in (!name!) do (
set pth=%%~dpf
set name=%%~nf
set ending=%%~xf
set datsave=%%~nxf

set "name=!name!_!date:~6,4!!date:~3,2!!date:~0,2!!ending!


echo renaming "!datsave!" to "!name!"
rem ren "!datsave!" "!name!"

popd
)

)
```

- `paths.txt` contains just a line `C:\full\path\to\test\*.txt`
- my `test` directory contains 2 text files and 1 other file

output:

```
renaming "bar.txt" to "bar_20160812.txt"
renaming "foo.txt" to "foo_20160812.txt"
```

(just uncomment the `ren` line to get the job done)

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! Tested it and it still works for full paths, but this line:
    `C:\foo\bar\*.*`
gets completely ignored... If I put in a timeout to see echos built in the program, I can see that the path is totally left out from the progress, eventhough it is put in the paths.txt correctly.
Any ideas?

Comment: EDIT: It does NOT get ignored! It looks like he changes the directory, but then does not go further and onto the next path given.

Comment: In fact, he sets name to the path without the drive-letter, pushes the directory, shows it properly and then does not proceed...

Comment: Great finding with `~nx` modifier! But there is an issue: `set name=!z:*\=!` removes everything up to the *first* backslash, so `C:\foo\bar\*.*` becomes `foo\bar\*.*`... And I recommend to *not* use variable `path` as this is system-reserved...

Comment: But it works for all other paths, when there are no wildcards...
And i do not use path; it is just renamed for this case :)

Comment: @aschipfl: honored by your comment. A variant could be to substitute directory name by nothing.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 so you confirm it works with wildcards, but you're suggesting that it fails when there are full paths right? Aside: show your boss how people are busting the a** to help you and they struggle. I could write a python solution in 10 minutes and it would be more maintanable.

Comment: Given that `!z!` contains a full path, `!path!` should hold parent (drive and path) of `!z!`; so you could replace `!path!` by nothing in `z`, so something like `set "name=!z:*!path!=!"` (I know nested delayed expansion does not work but you might understand what you mean; work-arounds for the nested delayed expansion can be found in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38241938), it is just too much for a comment post)...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre well... exactly the opposite. No wildcards->works; wildcards->does not work. Yeah I would be happier to work with open pascal (programming during school in lazarus) or even java (which I now have learned for about a month or so)... I think I will go forward and ask if it is enough if there is a working executable file that does the job...
Thanks for all your help  :)

Comment: @geisterfurz007 I could make it work with full paths + wildcards.

Comment: @aschipfl: I think you'll like the stupid thing I did instead of the double variable expansion: `for /L %%I in (1,1,20) do set name=!name:*\=!` Works great.

Comment: I see, not bad, but a path could contain more than 20 elements (directories); I think there is a limit for path depths though...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre How hard would it be? As a batch newbie I would like to follow the process :)

Comment: @aschipfl: I have added a check so it is safe

Comment: @geisterfurz007: I updated the post, should be ok for you; I can post the python solution for comparison

Comment: First of all thanks for another quick and helpful response. I checked everything and my code is basically yours now (except for a few pause and echos for testing reasons), but there is still some problem left, I cannot explain myself (Does not mean that much anyways :D): After renaming the first file from the directory correctly, the programm struggles with all other files, because the directory gets changed to early. I thought `pushd "!pth!"` had to get into the for-loop but that did not work. 
Sadly I do not know anything about python, so I would not understand your code there well...

Comment: Ok, that would mean that we will have to generate a new .bat file containing the renaming instructions, and call it later. Possible.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre So the thought basically is to give all the parameters set by the current one to another batchfile to make sure no other paths are set?