# batch delete with directory variable - windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file

I use the following batch file to delete unwanted files on several drives.

```
set /p DELPATH=<"C:\DELETE-ALL.txt" 

for /f "usebackq delims=;" %%i in ("C:\DELETE-ALL.txt") do @del /q "D:\HFI\%DELPATH%\%%i" > C:\DELETE-ALL-4.txt 2>&1
... same command for other local and network drives.
```

The DELETE-ALL.txt looks like this:

```
mydirectory
TEST.xlsx
TEST2.xlsx
```

This works great. It deletes files in single directory. But now I need it to do more. I need the batch file to delete files in different directories. So, it boils down to how to change directory on the fly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You expect me to believe that a command that expands to `@del /q "D:\HFI\D:\mydirectory\D:\mydirectory"` works?

Comment: Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: You might want to have a look [on this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911430/rename-files-using-wildcard-paths/38941888#38941888). You can put in Directory/filenames (including wildcards) and rename them with that code. Just change the `ren` to `del` and it should be ok for your purpose. It is quite big, but it works great for me. Notice the comment at the end to in/exclude subfolders.

Comment: Thanks. Most of the commands in that file are beyond my head. I'll see what I can learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turns out to be easier than I thought. Although my original question was for deleting files, I got it to work for rename. It should work for delete with little modification.

```
 @(for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=;" %%A in ('"TYPE C:\RENAME-ALL.txt"') do (
 @echo "%%A" | find /i "\" 
  @if errorlevel 1 (
  RENAME "%%A" "%%B" >> C:\RENAME-ALL-4.txt 2>&1
  ) ELSE (
 CD /D D:\mydirectory\%%A
  )
 )
 )
```

The script looks for "\". If found, it assumes that line is a directory and change to the corresponding directory with "D:\mydirectory\" as a path prefix. Otherwise, it assumes the line contains file name. Since back slash is not allowed in filename, the assumption is safe.

Hope this will help other people.

Answer (score 0):

I answer you here because i can't comment now with my lower reputation.

I strongely recommend to use PowerShell or python or others program scripts to do this. Using windows batch, it will take you more time to find a good way and there may be no way to do such a little complex misson.